# Is the server running on host "localhost" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? & raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, gunicorn

I have looked at other posts on Stackoverflow but none of the solutions are working in my case. I have a Flask app using PostgresSQL that I am trying to deploy in Heroku. I was told that there is an application error and to run this code to track the error - `heroku logs --tail`.

[image: screenshot]

So the main errors that I am looking at is `Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?` and `raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR) gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>`

```
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514972+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/run.py", line 3, in <module>
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514972+00:00 app[web.1]: app = create_app()
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514972+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/script/__init__.py", line 19, in create_app
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514972+00:00 app[web.1]: db.create_all()
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514972+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1039, in create_all
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514973+00:00 app[web.1]: self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514973+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1031, in _execute_for_all_tables
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514973+00:00 app[web.1]: op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514973+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 4554, in create_all
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514973+00:00 app[web.1]: ddl.SchemaGenerator, self, checkfirst=checkfirst, tables=tables
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514974+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2094, in _run_visitor
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514974+00:00 app[web.1]: with self._optional_conn_ctx_manager(connection) as conn:
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514974+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514974+00:00 app[web.1]: return next(self.gen)
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514975+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2086, in _optional_conn_ctx_manager
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514975+00:00 app[web.1]: with self._contextual_connect() as conn:
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514975+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2302, in _contextual_connect
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514975+00:00 app[web.1]: self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, None),
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514976+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2340, in _wrap_pool_connect
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514976+00:00 app[web.1]: e, dialect, self
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514976+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1584, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514977+00:00 app[web.1]: sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514977+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514977+00:00 app[web.1]: raise exception
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514977+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2336, in _wrap_pool_connect
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514977+00:00 app[web.1]: return fn()
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514978+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 364, in connect
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514978+00:00 app[web.1]: return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514978+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 778, in _checkout
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514978+00:00 app[web.1]: fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514979+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 495, in checkout
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514980+00:00 app[web.1]: rec = pool._do_get()
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514980+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 140, in _do_get
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514983+00:00 app[web.1]: self._dec_overflow()
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514983+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514983+00:00 app[web.1]: with_traceback=exc_tb,
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514983+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514983+00:00 app[web.1]: raise exception
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514984+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 137, in _do_get
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514984+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._create_connection()
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514984+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 309, in _create_connection
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514984+00:00 app[web.1]: return _ConnectionRecord(self)
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514984+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 440, in __init__
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514985+00:00 app[web.1]: self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514985+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 661, in __connect
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514985+00:00 app[web.1]: pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514985+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514986+00:00 app[web.1]: with_traceback=exc_tb,
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514986+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514986+00:00 app[web.1]: raise exception
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514987+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 656, in __connect
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514987+00:00 app[web.1]: connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514990+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 114, in connect
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514990+00:00 app[web.1]: return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514990+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 493, in connect
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514990+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514991+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514991+00:00 app[web.1]: conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514992+00:00 app[web.1]: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514992+00:00 app[web.1]: Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514992+00:00 app[web.1]: TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514992+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-22T13:21:05.514993+00:00 app[web.1]: (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
2020-11-22T13:21:05.515379+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-22 13:21:05 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-11-22T13:21:05.576121+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-11-22T13:21:05.576131+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in run
2020-11-22T13:21:05.576401+00:00 app[web.1]: self.sleep()
2020-11-22T13:21:05.576404+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 357, in sleep
2020-11-22T13:21:05.576660+00:00 app[web.1]: ready = select.select([self.PIPE[0]], [], [], 1.0)
2020-11-22T13:21:05.576661+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2020-11-22T13:21:05.576819+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2020-11-22T13:21:05.576842+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2020-11-22T13:21:05.577080+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2020-11-22T13:21:05.577115+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2020-11-22T13:21:05.577116+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-22T13:21:05.577116+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2020-11-22T13:21:05.577116+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-22T13:21:05.577118+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-11-22T13:21:05.577136+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
2020-11-22T13:21:05.577272+00:00 app[web.1]: sys.exit(run())
2020-11-22T13:21:05.577288+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in run
2020-11-22T13:21:05.577399+00:00 app[web.1]: WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2020-11-22T13:21:05.577401+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 228, in run
2020-11-22T13:21:05.577564+00:00 app[web.1]: super().run()
2020-11-22T13:21:05.577566+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
2020-11-22T13:21:05.577679+00:00 app[web.1]: Arbiter(self).run()
2020-11-22T13:21:05.577681+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 229, in run
2020-11-22T13:21:05.577824+00:00 app[web.1]: self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
2020-11-22T13:21:05.577826+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt
2020-11-22T13:21:05.578053+00:00 app[web.1]: self.stop()
2020-11-22T13:21:05.578055+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
2020-11-22T13:21:05.578265+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1)
2020-11-22T13:21:05.578267+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2020-11-22T13:21:05.578438+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2020-11-22T13:21:05.578442+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2020-11-22T13:21:05.578739+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2020-11-22T13:21:05.578742+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2020-11-22T13:21:05.640224+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-11-22T13:21:05.684389+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

This is my config.py

```
import os

class Config:
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')
```

where SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql://localhost/poetry_db' and SECRET_KEY are both exported as environment variables.

This is my **init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager
from script.config import Config

db = SQLAlchemy()
bcrypt = Bcrypt()
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = 'users.login'
login_manager.login_message_category = 'info'

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    db.init_app(app)
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    from script.users.routes import users
    from script.posts.routes import posts
    from script.messages.routes import messages
    from script.main.routes import main
    app.register_blueprint(users)
    app.register_blueprint(posts)
    app.register_blueprint(messages)
    app.register_blueprint(main)
    from script.errors.handlers import errors 
    app.register_blueprint(errors)

    return app
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message is saying that your web process isn't able to connect to your database. In local development, usually you have a database on the same machine as you are developing, so `localhost` / `127.0.0.1` is the address that your web app can use to find your database.

But in Heroku, the database is an add-on (https://www.heroku.com/postgres). So Heroku provisions and manages the database on Amazon AWS on a different machine than where your web app is running. The URL should look something like `ec2-11-22-3343-44.compute-1.amazonaws.com`. This information is shown on the database add-on summary page, along with the `database` and the `username` and `password`. Each piece is needed to form a connection string.

What you need to do is supply environment variables. Heroku calls them config vars: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars. With those in place, you tell your app to pull those variables to get the connection URL. See an example at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-python

```
import os

DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']

# Add this to your app settings / connect using DATABASE_URL
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply! Since the Postgresql is a Heroku add on, I assume the config vars are saved in Heroku? Do I need to export DATABASE_URL as environment variables on my own machine? (I did anyway just in case) Also, do I replace `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')` with `DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']` in config.py? That is what I did, and when I pushed it to Heroku, the website itself loads but every page is a 404 error, do I need to do something else? Thanks!

Comment: `os.environ.get(KEY)` is the same as `os.environ[KEY]` except that the first has a default value if `KEY` doesn't exist and the second raises an exception if `KEY` doesn't exist.

Comment: Look where your `postgresql://localhost/poetry_db` is set. It should be the Heroku config vars. Use the Heroku CLI to get the connection details. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-credentials